# changing faces for deadlines in org

Tags: org-agenda, faces, deadline

Using this code

```
(defcustom org-agenda-deadline-faces
   '((1.0 . org-warning)
    (0.5 . org-upcoming-deadline)
    (0.0 . org-upcoming-distant-deadline))
```

1. How do you replace "org-warning" with a specific color code? What would be the syntax?
2. I tried to copy paste that into my init, but it gives me a parsing error.

Comment: One error is that the parentheses don't match: you need a closing paren at the end.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: My question is how to replace org-warning with some code. For instance, make foreground black.